# Javascript how to make a sound effect go off?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that makes a sound after a click, I found threads on audio.play(), but to my understanding that requires some sort of embedded player? I want the sound to go off independent of anything on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```js
Audio.prototype.stop = function() {
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;
};
```

And call it using:

```js
audio.stop();
```

This extends the default Audio class, and works perfectly.